# how do I send the ouput from azure ml model to eventhub?

Tags: python, api, azure-eventhub, azure-machine-learning-service

Hi I'm new to Azure ML and have little knowledge of it.
I've built a azure ml model using automl package and generated some outputs to be sent to the eventhub.

Our data flow would be azure ml -> eventhub -> adls -> sql dw...
I've registered the model but not sure how to deploy it.
I looked up some documents and it's all about having webservice as the endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Here is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-endpoints) to the Azure Machine Learning endpoints (preview) to streamline model deployments for both real-time and batch inference deployments.

We usually recommend to use [Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/machine-learning-udf) to get fully managed streaming processing. In addition to send data to SQL for the heatmap, Azure Stream Analytics can work with PBI streaming datasets. ASA is also a good choice for low latency (second or less) and complex queries.

Sample Repo:https://github.com/JackXueIndiana/Azure-Stream-Analysis-AML-WS-Call

Comment: Hi could you help me with another problem Im facing in azure ml? Im trying to deploy my model but Im continually getting the same error It seems like there r some problems with my code.. I need somebody to take a look at.. here is the link of my question- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/663147/getting-an-error3434acideploymentfailed34.html